# RP Pico won't connect to PC

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I created a blink program with cmake in a VM and loaded it onto the pico from Windows. The pico disconnected, but it did not blink, and it does not reconnect to my windows pc.

I tried unplugging it and holding down the bootsel button. It seems kinda bricked.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, but a "how to use this board hardware" question. This would be more suitable for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

fixed. held down bootsel while plugging in